# How to handle special characters in html element id/name in Jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a HTML form which uses special characters in ids ( :,-,_ ). The form uses JQuery validation plugin to validate the user input. Specifically the id includes a GUID, 
Following is the sample code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#respondForm').validate({ onclick: false,
                onkeyup: false,
                onfocusout: false,
                highlight:
function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).css({ backgroundColor: '#FFFF88' });
}
,
                errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div.error-container')),
                wrapper: 'li',
                rules: { Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405:
{
    required: true
, minlength: 5
, maxlength: 10
}

                }
,
                messages: { firstName:
{
    required: "xxx_Required"
, minlength: "XXX Should be greater than 5"
, maxlength: "XXX Cannot be greater than 10"
}

                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Home/Submit" method="post" id="respondForm">  
   <div>
    <div class="error-container">
    <ul>

    </ul>
    </div>   
    </div>
    <div>    
        <input type="text" id="Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405" name="Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405" />        
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br />

    </div>
</form>
```

As you can observe input type text element has the id/name as "`Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405`"

If I run this page in the browser, I receive a JavaScript error:

> Webpage error details
>
> Message: Expected '}'
>   Line: 23
>   Char: 50
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://localhost:64603/

The error is pointing to this line:

```
function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).css({ backgroundColor: '#FFFF88' });
}
,
                errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div.error-container')),
                wrapper: 'li',
***[Line 23] ----->   rules: { Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405:***
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Wrap your id in quotes (in the JavaScript).

Comment: Also, note that it’s not the ID, but the NAME attribute you’re using here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Crescent Fresh" your suggestion worked, wrapping the id in single quotes:

```
rules: { 'Input:_CDD66FA6-D190-434D-AF51-8272F64E0646_14ecbb3f-c0e0-4caf-b03a-013d12118405':
{
```

makes it work