# How to use/transmit attr('id') containing special chars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I have searched for some questions regarding this (like [How to handle special characters in html element id/name in Jquery validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706159/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-html-element-id-name-in-jquery-validation)), but unfortunately it doesn't help me, or I didn't undertsood the trick...

Let's say we have a button, with a class `.bt` and the id `my|id`. (or other special separators like `,:;|`)

It doesn't seem to be possible to use it to match another element like `$('#other_'+$('.bt').attr('id'))`

You can see an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JX4Rr/1/).

So my question, is how to transmit those specials characters (`,:;|`) ?

Comment: Special characters must be escaped with \\. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ok, thanks, so how could I do that in this case ? With a `replace('|','\|',id)` ? or other method ?

Comment: Why are you putting those special characters in your IDs? `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` - [Basic HTML data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Comment: @couzzi that's true in HTML4, but not HTML5.

Comment: @couzzi the html5 spec is a lot less strict on this topic. Even if he is using html4, most browsers will still allow it.

Comment: @Valky Yes, you would need to do a find/replace on the special characters.

Comment: Well I'll be dammed! Just read [this](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class). Good to know. Thanks gents.

Comment: @couzzi `'-' and ':'` doesn't seem to work anyway.

Comment: @couzzi try them here http://jsfiddle.net/JX4Rr/1/

Comment: @Valky — sorted it out. See updated answer/fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a deviation from pure-jQuery solutions, but maybe in this case it's better to use native `document.getElementById(...)` function?

```
$(document.getElementById('other_' + $('.bt').attr('id')))
```

It reads a bit more verbose, but seems more clear/consistent/safe than mucking about with regexes.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this solution, it works too, but couzzi solution is better using jquery.

Comment: The solution offered by couzzi is more concise, but does not escape `"` characters and also may have performance issues (not that it matters). YMMV :)

Comment: Yes, regarding the comments on it, I'm going to check your answer that is faster to execute by the client.

Comment: @couzzi yes, sorry your solution was nice too, but slower, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
$('[id="div_' + id + '"]').html(id);
```

instead of this:

```
$('#div_'+id).html(id);
```

<strike>Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JX4Rr/2/)</strike>

-Edit-

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JX4Rr/3/) that shows usage of `,:;|`

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, it seems to be the better solution using jquery selector, without regexp/replace.

Comment: Good suggestion, but this will take extra work since the browser can't use `document.getElementById` which is faster. jQuery will either have to use Sizzle (and parse it first, maybe eventually using `getElementById`), or `document.querySelectorAll`. Not that you'll notice it, but it's something to remember at least

Comment: Good point Ian! I think it comes down to the lesser of two evils.

Comment: mmh, so I guess that it's better checking Nick Matantsev reply ?

Comment: @couzzi Yeah it's hard to justify which route is actually better...especially since we're talking about finding by `id` - a relatively quick operation in any case. Another thing to consider is that if `document.querySelectorAll` is used (internally by jQuery, or explicitly), it will return multiple elements if an `id` is duplicated...that's off topic, but interesting...and of course, you should never duplicate `id`s, but I'm just saying. `document.getElementById` always returns the first element found by that `id`

Comment: @Ian - True, on all counts, but my main contention is using `document.getElementById` in parallel with jQuery; while totally valid, it just **feels** wrong.

Comment: @couzzi That's exactly what I was thinking. Hahaha

Comment: @Ian so what is the better solution ?

Comment: @couzzi - haha, I totally agree - using native DOM calls feels "hairy" here. I also checked if jQuery allows SQL-like `?` placeholders in the selectors but nope...

Comment: This is relevant and a good read: [http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$('#other_' + $('.bt').attr('id').replace('|', '\\|'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S669p/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it appears that the other replies are better, +1 anyway (doesn't need the -1 you get by other users)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that still uses the `id` selector, but also allows for any special characters you want to be able to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bt").on("click", function () {
        var escaped = $(this).attr("id").replace(/([,:;|])/g, "\\$1");
        console.log("escaped: " + escaped);
        $("#other_" + escaped).toggleClass("testing");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bz3Kw/1/

Comment: +1 Thanks, this works, but I keep it for another use, because other replies seems lighter.